# How do I create foam around the object?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

[image]

I can do it, but using dynamic paint, baking the image and using it as a coordinate

[image]

But the waveform completely misses the design! in this image I used texture coordinate and used monkey as value...

I want to match 1 more image without losing the wave design! And I want it not to have to rely on baked image... how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is useful, but you can use AO to do at least something similar.
Check this out:
[image: AO1]

[image: AO2]

Maybe tweaking colorRamp, adding noise texture, etc...?